# Fragment Not Showing in the Activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I have tried everything but i am not able to find the bug in the code what was it, i want to show the fragment in the activity but the fragment is not showing, What i have tried is

followed instruction as per https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#kotlin, result = not worked.

Watched and followed 6 to 10 youtube tutorials, result = not worked.

tried to find the solution on the google, result = tried and checked everything as per every single article but not worked.
Tried different layouts in the XML layout file like as Fragment, FrameLayout,  <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

i was learning the java for android dvelopment but when i know that the primary language for android development is kotlin then i just move to the kotlin.

So i am very new to kotlin please tell me what is the problem why the fragment is not working.

MainActivity

```
package com.ak_applications.kottry.screens

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import com.ak_applications.kottry.R

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       val btnGo: Button = findViewById(R.id.btn_go)

       btnGo.setOnClickListener {
           startActivity(Intent(this, login_signup::class.java))
       }
    }
}
```

MainActiviy.Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".screens.MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/blue_and_purple">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
        android:id="@+id/btn_go"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        app:strokeColor="@color/white"
        app:strokeWidth="1dp"
        android:text="GO"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:elevation="34dp"
        app:rippleColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Class in which i want to show the fragment.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"/>
    
</LinearLayout>
```

Class

```
package com.ak_applications.kottry.screens

import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
import com.ak_applications.kottry.R
import com.ak_applications.kottry.screens.fragments.login_fragment

class login_signup: AppCompatActivity(R.layout.login_signup_layout) {
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState)
        
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add(R.id.frag_container, login_fragment())
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Fragment that i want to show

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".screens.fragments.login_fragment"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_semi_bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:letterSpacing="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_login_des"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter Your Credintials to get access"
        android:textColor="#9CFFFFFF"
        android:fontFamily="@font/raleway_medium"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_login"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/user_id_feild"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
        app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#FF0000"
        app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
        app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
        app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/user_active_state"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/txt_login_des"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/password_feild"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:hint="Email or User name or Phone Number"
            android:textColorHint="#74FFFFFF"
            android:padding="10dp"/>

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/password_feild"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            app:boxStrokeColor="@color/white"
            app:boxStrokeErrorColor="#FF0000"
            app:boxStrokeWidth="1dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="8dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="8dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="8dp"
            app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="8dp"
            app:startIconDrawable="@drawable/lock_unlock_anime"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/user_id_feild"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/btn_signIn"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="•••••••••••••"
                android:textColorHint="#74FFFFFF"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_signIn"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/password_feild"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fbtn_google"
            app:strokeColor="@color/white"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp"
            app:rippleColor="@color/black"/>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_register"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Register"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/fbtn_google"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn_signIn"
            app:rippleColor="@color/black"
            app:strokeColor="@color/white"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtn_google"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#6F000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:elevation="35dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/google_cute_icon"
            android:tintMode="add"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fbtn_facebook"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
            android:background="@drawable/icons8_facebook"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/fbtn_google"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
            app:elevation="35dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icons8_facebook"
            android:tintMode="add"
            app:maxImageSize="30dp"/>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fbtn_twitter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="#6F000000"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/fbtn_google"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        app:elevation="35dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/google_cute_icon"
        android:tintMode="add"/>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment Class

```
package com.ak_applications.kottry.screens.fragments

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.View
import com.ak_applications.kottry.R

class login_fragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_login_fragment) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

Plase help me out i don't understand what is the issue with my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `login_signup` activity, change the `onCreate()` from

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, persistentState: PersistableBundle?)
```

to

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tuan Chau, appreciate your help thanks again

Comment: No worries. It's really confused API. Next time, you can check by printing something to see if the code is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what the problem might be, but I'll give a couple of possible solutions.

1st:
Try using a `FragmentContainerView` to contain your fragment. Something like this:

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/frag_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="PATH TO YOUR FRAGMENT">
```

In the name tag you can out the path to the fragment that you want to inflate first.
The path should something like com.ak_applications.kottry.login_fragment.

2nd:
You can try a different way to use the `supportFragmentManager`. I use it like this:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag_container, login_fragment()).commit()
```

Just give it a go on any of the two.

Comment: after removing the persistentState all layout work just fine

Comment: Personally, I don't encourage using `FragmentContainerView` due to obfuscation. I got an error that class not found on production but worked during debugging. It's really easy to forget to keep the fragment name in obfuscation config since not all fragments require that.